# WebLogic 12c and Spring MVC error 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, weblogic

I'm facing a problem with a Spring MVC / Spring Security project that I'm trying to run over WebLogic 12c. The project was created using Tomcat, but over WL I always have an error 403 (http.../project/), or 404 when I try to open what should work as a normal URL (http.../project/users/).

The project works with Spring MVC (4.3.0.RELEASE), Spring Security (4.1.1.RELEASE) and Thymeleaf (3.0.1.RELEASE)

The web.xml file contains:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

And the weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<context-root>project</context-root>
<session-descriptor>
    <cookie-name>PROJECT</cookie-name>
    <cookie-path>/project</cookie-path>
</session-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

The whole Spring configuration was made using Java and not XML files.

I have been trying different options that I have found here and other forums but until now I can't find a solution.

Comment: I'm using WebLogic 12.1.3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this way.
For the classes used to initialize application and security, implements **WebApplicationInitializer**. My specific case had another issue with the JNDI, but it was solved with few lines in the *weblogic.xml* and a param for the annotation in the data source for the JPA class.